# Java Web, Struts2 filter, always check file not exists, causes cache leak

Tags: java, servlets, memory-leaks, struts2, filter

I'm running a struts2 web project on Tomcat7.

I made an empty servlet, then
I did a test via python requests(no matter what, just for loop post, you can use ab、seige or some other client to test):

```
for i in range (0,20000000):
  r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/aaa/emptyservlet", files={'file': open('./req.txt')}, data={'a':'aaaa'});
  ....
```

On the server side, Tomcat received a http post request of "multipart/form-data", and my emptyservlet did nothing.

This was just a simple test and everything ran normally. 
But I found that, if you added struts2 filter to the url, a strange problem occurred:

```
(add a StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, and set it to /*)

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    ....
  <filter-mapping>
```

then, as you doing the loop requests, the java process seemed to stat many null file:

```
$ strace -p 17591 -fe trace=open
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184476.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184477.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184476.tmp", O_RDONLY) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184478.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184479.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184478.tmp", O_RDONLY) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184480.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184481.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184480.tmp", O_RDONLY) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184482.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184483.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184482.tmp", O_RDONLY) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184484.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184485.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184484.tmp", O_RDONLY) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184490.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
[pid 17620] open("/data/project/tempdir/upload_cfe3c79b_9adf_4069_a177_ecca0097b030_01184491.tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 46
....
```

And this will cause linux dentry cache leak:

```
$  cat /proc/slabinfo | grep dentry      
dentry            3860290 3860300    192   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata 193015 193015    480
$  cat /proc/slabinfo | grep dentry
dentry            3862046 3862060    192   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata 193103 193103    480
$  cat /proc/slabinfo | grep dentry
dentry            3863361 3863380    192   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata 193169 193169    480
$  cat /proc/slabinfo | grep dentry
dentry            4090300 4090300    192   20    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata 204515 204515    120

....
```

You would see that dentry increasing all the time.

If you remove the Struts2 Filter in web.xml, the phenomenon will disappear.

So, is this a bug? Or how to avoid the cache leak?...

Comment: do these files stay there when you shutdown your JVM?

Comment: @Yogi: no, no file generated, the dir always empty. All these files were not exists.

Comment: I think then its struts2 framework which is just creating tmp files for its processing. If files are not flushed from time to time while application is deployed whether empty or not in `/data/project/tempdir/` and they keep on piling up then you might be onto something else it should be normal.

Comment: @Yogi:Sorry my english is poor, so i can't understand your means :(...

Comment: @lonelycoder have you tried the answer provided ? Have you excluded your servlet in action configuration ?

Comment: @Andrea Ligios: I tried excluded, cache leak still there.

Answer (score 0):

When using Struts2, you should use `Action`s instead of `Servlet`s whenever it's possible.

- Actions are Thread-Safe, while Servlets are not;
- Actions are "surrounded" (intercepted before and after Action execution) by ready-to-use Interceptors, while for Servlets you need to write your own Servlet Filters from scratch.

By the way, if for some reason you need to use a Servlet instead of an Action, you need to exclude it from being intercepted by the `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

You can do that in struts configuration (struts.xml) like follows, for both a single servlet :

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/NameOfServletToExclude"/>
```

or multiple patterns :

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*unfiltered.*,.*\\.nofilter"/>
```

as described [in the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/webxml.html).

Comment: I tried excludePattern(value="/aaa/emptyservlet"), but the cache leak still here...

Comment: Try with only /emptyservlet, aaa seems to be your context

Comment: I tried only /emptyservletn(value="/emptyservlet"), still cache leak :(